# unexpected type changed version control

Tags: git, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, libgit2, libgit2sharp

Ok, so I recently did a bunch changes to a project I have. More than anything I migrated from Xamarin Studios Mac to Visual Studios Mac.

When I try to commit my changes I am getting an error in version control that says the following:

- Entry "iOS/debug/.../..."bears Unexpected Changekind 'typedChanged'. I can uncheck the commit for those files, but I need to be able to commit my whole project.

How can I fix this? what does the error even mean? I went from bitbucket to team services.

Comment: In Git-ese, a "type change" occurs when something goes from ordinary file to symbolic link, or symlink to ordinary file, or (less likely) submodule reference to file or similar. Why that should have happened here, and why whatever software you're using is *upset* by that, are questions I cannot answer.

Comment: can you commit using commandline git? If it fails please provde the error messages